Access to open ports inside a network-namespace
I have a network-namespace created by WireGuard and a tinyproxy defined as:
age.identityPaths = [ "..." ];
age.secrets.protonvpn.file = ./protonvpn.age;
networking.wireguard.interfaces.protonvpn = {
  interfaceNamespace = "protonvpn";
  preSetup = "test -f /run/netns/protonvpn || ip netns add protonvpn || test -f /run/netns/protonvpn";
  postSetup = ''
    ${pkgs.iproute2}/bin/ip link add veth-main type veth peer name veth-protonvpn
    ${pkgs.iproute2}/bin/ip link set veth-protonvpn netns protonvpn
    ${pkgs.iproute2}/bin/ip addr add 192.168.100.1/24 dev veth-main
    ${pkgs.iproute2}/bin/ip netns exec protonvpn ip addr add 192.168.100.100/24 dev veth-protonvpn
    ${pkgs.iproute2}/bin/ip link set veth-main up
    ${pkgs.iproute2}/bin/ip netns exec protonvpn ip link set veth-protonvpn up
    ${pkgs.iproute2}/bin/ip route add 192.168.100.100 dev veth-main
  '';

  privateKeyFile = config.age.secrets.protonvpn.path;
  ips = [ "10.2.0.2/32" ];

  peers = [{
    publicKey = "...";
    endpoint = "...";
    allowedIPs = [ "0.0.0.0/0" "::/0" ];
  }];
};

services.tinyproxy = {
  enable = true;
  settings = {
    Allow = "0.0.0.0/0";
    Listen = "0.0.0.0";
    Port = 31281;
  };
};

systemd.services.tinyproxy =  {
  bindsTo = [ "wireguard-protonvpn.service" ];
  after = [ "wireguard-protonvpn.service" ];
  serviceConfig.NetworkNamespacePath = "/run/netns/protonvpn";
};

Interfaces are properly set-up:
$ ip addr
...
11: veth-main@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:5e:2f:14:dd:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns protonvpn
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 scope global veth-main
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f4e0:7aff:fe81:10da/64 scope link proto kernel_ll 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

In the namespace:
$ sudo ip netns exec protonvpn ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: protonvpn: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.2.0.2/32 scope global protonvpn
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: veth-protonvpn@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ae:d1:5f:b6:e2:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.100.100/24 scope global veth-protonvpn
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::acd1:5fff:feb6:e2a5/64 scope link proto kernel_ll 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I can ping back-and-forth, services are running properly, but I can't connect to it:
$ curl --proxy http://192.168.100.100:31281 https://ifconfig.co
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.100.100 port 31281 after 134699 ms: Could not connect to server

How can I configure my network-namespace so I can connect to it?
